# Regex: Match Numbers inside a bracket

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Ok here is an example of the text I got

```
"data": [
  {
     "post_id": "164902600239452_10202071734744222",
     "actor_id": 164902600239452,
     "target_id": null,
     "likes": {
        "href": "https://www.facebook.com/browse/likes/?id=10202071734744222",
        "count": 2,
        "sample": [
       678063648,
       100000551340876,
       100000805495404,
       100000905843684,
        ],
        "friends": [

        ],
        "user_likes": false,
        "can_like": true
     },
     "comments": {
        "can_remove": false,
        "can_post": true,
        "count": 0,
        "comment_list": [

        ]
     },
     "message": "Down to the FINAL 3 SEATS for It Factor LIVE 2013... WHO will snag them before we close registration on October 15th???\n\nLearn more now at http://www.ItFactorLIVE.com/"
  }, ]
```

I want to match only the numbers inside the brackets after the "sample":

```
            "sample": [
       678063648,
       100000551340876,
       100000805495404,
       100000905843684,
        ],
```

so that I end up with this

```
           678063648
           100000551340876
           100000805495404
           100000905843684
```

May somebody please help me with the correct regex to make that happen?

Comment: That looks like a job for a JSON parser, not a regexp. In particular, I don't know any regexp implementation that allows variable-length lookbehinds, which (if I am not mistaken) is what you would require to solve this in the way you're thinking of.

Comment: Agree with the JSON comment - but wouldn't `/\[(?:(\d+)[^\d])\]/g` do the trick?

Comment: Is this all one string, or do you want to process this one line at a time? Possible solution at http://regex101.com/r/xQ6bN5

Comment: I have never done JSON parse and the system I am using to make this happen doesn't support it so I am stuck with regex so I was hoping to see if was possible to do it on regex if I use \d+ I can match the numbers but at soon I add \[\d+\] to match at least one of the numbers inside the brackets it doesn't work

Comment: @Floris thanks a lot as that works on that portion of code but when when I add it as a whole it matches many other places as well, I will edit the main question to add the full code

Comment: @Wiseguy I am using .NET regular expression engine

Comment: @Amadan .NET allows variable-length lookbehinds. Java does, too, as long as it's finite-length (e.g., `.{1,100}`). On a different note, several flavors support the `\G` assertion, which could simplify this task without the use of lookbehinds.

Comment: @Wiseguy: I stand corrected, I should have said non-finite-length lookbehinds. Oniguruma and similar "regular expression engines" that go way past regular expression languages is why I explicitly said "in the way you're thinking of", given that the question is tagged with `regex-lookarounds`.

Comment: @Floris here is what happens when I use your regex in the full code [link](http://regex101.com/r/aE2pJ3) Do you know any way to get the numbers inside the brackets after the "sample": ? Your or anybody's help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Floris: No, that will match the whole bracket, and capture one of the numbers. The question asks about matching the numbers (and only numbers).

Comment: Is [this what your looking for](http://regex101.com/r/uN5zZ8) ?

Comment: @hwnd thanks so MUCH! looks like that did the tick. This saved my day big time.

Comment: @hwnd: It will match `8` in `"weird_smiley": "8 ]"`. It does not match inside brackets. Just stop with this insanity and use `JavaScriptSerializer.DeserializeObject`.

Comment: Yes using a parser is the right way to do this here.

Comment: @Amadan .NET _does_ support infinite-length lookbehinds. Try `(?<="sample": \[[\s\d,]*)\d+` on [regexhero.net](http://regexhero.net/tester/).

Comment: @Wiseguy: I apologise, I misunderstood. But I shall ignore your link (Silverlight doesn't like Chrome on Mac).

Comment: @Amadan when I wrote that suggestion the question was MUCH simpler...

Comment: @Wiseguy that works great I tested it on a very large document and it returned all the data I need correctly thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - I have looked at the solution that @hwnd had suggested, as well as the link you gave to the "real" data, and came up with the following:

```
\d+(?=,*\s+(?:\d|\]))
```

You can see at http://regex101.com/r/pL3gW2 that this matches every string of digits in the sample that is inside square brackets.

The key difference with @hwnd's solution was the addition of a `*` after the `,`, making the comma after the digits optional: this allows the expression to match the last set of numbers before the close `]`. Without it, the match skipped the last number inside the brackets.

It's been said before: there are powerful JSON parsers available in almost any language / platform. Look into them.

Answer (score 0):

see if this works for you
pattern = `(\d+)(?=(?:(?!\[).)*\])` [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/pW9uD0)